# call fgets from assembly code

Tags: c, nasm

I would like to know how to call fgets from assembly code.
I read these questions which are exactly the same as the this one: [How to call fgets in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689919/how-to-call-fgets-in-x86-assembly)
and this one: [How to use c library function fgets in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567055/how-to-use-c-library-function-fgets-in-assembly-language)
But both of them aren't satisfying for two reasons:
1. I really want to use fgets since i want my code to run on both windows and linux ( I'm using NASM )
2.I looked at the disassembled version of fgets, unfortunately it doesn't provide the necessary details to reproduce it naming how is `stdin` represented in assembly.
Here are my C and assembly codes i got by using `gcc -S fgets.c` .

fgets.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[15];
    fgets(name, 16, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

fgets.s

```
    .file   "fgets.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
.globl _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    __imp___iob, %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    $16, 4(%esp)
    leal    17(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _fgets
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .def    _fgets; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

First, i'm not good at reading AT&T syntax and thus understanding the above assembly source easily.
So can anyone help me figure out: (i) where is my local variable `name` located? in ESP+17 ? (ii) If `__imp___iob` is representing `stdin`, where is coming from so that i can use it?

Thanks

Comment: I also dislike that AT&T syntax.  Use `gcc -S -masm=intel fgets.c` to get a much nicer disassembly.

Comment: @Burr: hahaha, it's a bit discomforting. Thanks for the tip!!! Saved me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, name is at esp+17.  You'd be wise to initialize it.  Arguments in the cdecl calling conventions are passed right-to-left with the right-most deepest on the stack.  The `__imp___iob` is exported from the CRT, you'll find it back in the stdio.h header file.  Search for stdin.  The __imp prefix is a Microsoft convention to make exports from DLLs faster.  Getting this right is clearly the job of a compiler.

Comment: @Passant: I tracked `__imp_iob` back to some data defined probably in a DLL (ntdll.dll?). As you you just pointed out, the compiler is doing things great here but how do I get access to that value and use it too? I could do some `extern __imp_iob` in the `.text` section but, is it even correct? Welcome futher suggestions!

Comment: It is likely to be correct if the compiler generates it.  You'll have to link the same CRT library the compiler uses.  You seem to be mixing tools so it isn't exactly easy to make the call.  What is the point of this?

Comment: @Khan2011: I assume you're using MinGW.  `__imp_iob` is declared in `/mingww/include/stdio.h` and is resolved by the linker in `libmsvcrt.a`, the import library for msvcrt.dll. You should be able to use the same library to link your assembly program.  I'm not sure what (if any) special initialization the C runtime might need.  Spelunking through what MinGW does would answer that question.

Comment: @Passant: After your explanations, it's clear that i cannot rely on fgets. it is better to let C do the "printing" and "scanning" part in assembly for portability but calling fgets automatically discard the portability part. So there's no point in pursuing this futher.
@Burr: Thanks for the details. Investigating the CRT initialization part won't necessary any more [not portable]

Answer (score 1):

> (i) where is my local variable `name` located? in ESP+17 ?

Yes - actually 'name' decays to a pointer when you make the call - your entire array is on the stack.  The first byte is at ESP+17, the rest of the bytes follow.  Note that the code is using `leal` to get the *address* of that first byte of the array to pass to `fgets()`.

> (ii) If `__imp___iob` is representing stdin, where is coming from so that i can use it?

You should be able to just use whatever `stdin` gets defined to for your machine.  On my Mac, for example, it ends up being `___stdinp`.  You can chase down the definitions in your system headers (starting with `stdio.h`). You might need a `.globl` directive to make the assembler not complain, but it should link correctly.  `__imp___iob` looks like the right choice for you.

Here's what I found in my `stdio.h`:

```
#if __DARWIN_UNIX03
#define stdin   __stdinp
#define stdout  __stdoutp
#define stderr  __stderrp
#else /* !__DARWIN_UNIX03 */
#define stdin   (&__sF[0])
#define stdout  (&__sF[1])
#define stderr  (&__sF[2])
#endif /* __DARWIN_UNIX03 */
```

The extra `_` is required in my assembly code since the compiler isn't around to tack it on.

Comment: @Norum:Thanks for the clear explanation! I got my `stdin` in `stdio.h` but how to I use it in my assembly code? I have some code compiling but hey, can't do the job! I'm relatively new to stackoverflow so i'm not sure where to post my code. Thanks for any new insight!